# Need help to understand an equation in the image?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, self-learning

The image below is about Hoeffding's Inequalit from wikipedia, can somebody explain why the equation pointed by a red arrow becomes like that?

[image]

Comment: Its a combination of the two inequalities above. Try rewriting the left hand side in terms of the two probabilites above, using the rules you know.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I got it.